# Spark saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile java.io.IOException: Could not find a serializer for the Value class

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, serialization, hdfs

I'm trying to store a java pair RDD as a Hadoop sequence file as follows:

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> putRdd = ...
config.set("io.serializations","org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization,org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization");
putRdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(outputPath, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Put.class, SequenceFileOutputFormat.class, config);
```

But I get the exception even if I'm setting the `io.serializations`:

```
2017-04-06 14:39:32,623 ERROR [Executor task launch worker-0] executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: Could not find a serializer for the Value class: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put'. Please ensure that the configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're usingcustom serialization.
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:1192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1094)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getSequenceWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1014)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-04-06 14:39:32,669 ERROR [task-result-getter-0] scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
```

Any idea on how I can fix this??

Comment: What kind of data are you writing to HBase?

Comment: thanks @Vidya I already find the fix and shared below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the fix, apparently Put (and all HBase mutations) have a specific serialiser `MutationSerialization`.

The following line fixes the issue:

```
config.setStrings("io.serializations", 
    config.get("io.serializations"),
    MutationSerialization.class.getName(),
    ResultSerialization.class.getName());
```

Comment: I'm faced with a very similar case, but my type is: `JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>`, using the above class didn't help, any ideas which one I should be using? `Result` is imported from `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result`.

Comment: `ResultSerialization` should be enough, though if I try to do `putRdd.first()` or `putRdd.collect()` I still see a spark serialisation exception. In my case I just wanted to store to HDFS or back to HBase and the code above was enough.